# How to do aggregate functions in master detail relationship

Tags: relationships, master-detail

I have 2 objects student and course ..I want to calculate total number of students for particular course I have to find.

1. Count of students in each course
2. Student’s maximum fee in course
3. Minimum fee in course
4. Sum of paid fee, sum of balance fee

How to accomplish this in salesforce?

Comment: I think that what you want are [roll-up summary fields](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/fr/modules/point_click_business_logic/units/roll_up_summary_fields).

Answer (score 2):

Create roll up summary field in the Master object.
Use the below link to create a roll up summary:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&type=0

Let me know if it helps.